# Parameter warning: truncated value with size 32 to match size of target

Tags: verilog

I have a parameter as follows:

```
parameter PARAM = 7'd69;
```

When I try to assign that value to the register below:

```
reg [6:0] r;
```

Like this:

```
r <= PARAM;
```

I get synthesis warnings:

*Warning (10230): ... truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (7)*

This I assume is because `PARAM` is being interpreted as an integer because it is defined as a `parameter`. **Is there any way to define PARAM as 7 bits wide?**

I could always pass this in as a 7-bit input to my module, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define parameter as follow:

```
parameter [6:0]PARAM = 7'd69;
```

That way you're telling your compiler that `PARAM` size is 7 bits.